# RStudio won't allow me to install the package 'imager'

Tags: r, image-processing, anaconda, macos-sierra

Installed RStudio using Anaconda Navigator even though I already had RStudio and it was working fine before. The package 'imager' didn't load so I removed the application from Navigator and completely uninstall R and RStudio from my Macbook and reinstalled R and the application through Navigator, but that didn't fix things. Other packages install just fine. The following is the error message:

```
> library(imager)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘imager’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/omeedkashef/Library/R/3.4/library/imager/libs/imager.so':
  dlopen(/Users/omeedkashef/Library/R/3.4/library/imager/libs/imager.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/omeedkashef/Library/R/3.4/library/imager/libs/imager.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Try `devtools::install_github("dahtah/imager")`. Install first `install.packages("devtools")`.

Comment: installing from github gives me - configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted. ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘imager’

Comment: Perhaps you may want to consider http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Support/SelfHelpTools/HelpArticles/HelpArticles-Detail/TabId/2718/ArtMID/10220/ArticleID/18898/4085.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I did not have a problem installing `imager` from CRAN but did get an error message when trying to load the CRAN-installed package. When I tried installing from GitHub I got the more useful error message saying that X11 was not found (same as @andrii above). I solved all issues by installing X11 by downloading from this site: https://www.xquartz.org/

EDIT: I should mention that this is not a problem with RStudio per se, as the header of the question suggests, but rather just a dependency issue of one package (`imager`) on a not-explicitly R piece of sofware (X11).